# Why does it appear I am receiving an event twice

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have the following code that is logging receiving an event twice. Any ideas why? The received event message together with the event itself appear twice for every event received:

```
listen() {
        LOG.info('Awaiting events');
        this.bizNetworkConnection.on('event', (event) => {
            LOG.info('************Received Event**************');
            LOG.info(event);
            let options = {
                properties: { key:'value'}
            };
        });
}

static async listen(args) {
    let cr = new CommodityRegistry('commodityRegistry');
    await cr.init();
    let results = await cr.listen();
    LOG.info('Listened for events');
}
```

Comment: Improved formatting a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Composer currently listens for events from all peers (check your connection.json for the number of peers getting events). A client application will receive all of the events emitted by the business network, and it's up to the application to choose which/to what extent those events are integrated.